# Mockito issue - when(java.lang.Void) in Stubber cannot be applied to void

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I can't figure out why the `doNothing` isn't working for this? Any ideas?

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<GenericClass<someOtherClass>> captor;
...
Mockito.doNothing().when(mockObject.methodToStub(captor.capture()));
```

The error is:

> `Exception: when(java.lang.Void) in Stubber cannot be applied to void`

Answer (score 87):

This stub is wrong :

```
doNothing().when(mockObject.methodToStub(captor.capture())); // wrong
```

`methodToStub(...)` must be outside the `when` if using this API style (it should only contain the mock) :

```
doNothing().when(mockObject).methodToStub(captor.capture()); // correct
```

Tho remarks however :

1. `doNothing` is the default for void methods for a mock.
2. You can use the `BDDMockito` aliases that enables your code to be real *à la* Behavior Driven Development

Answer (score 9):

Although you ask why doNothing doesn't work, I get that you actually want to capture the argument for methodToStub.

The most straightforward way to do this would be:

```
verify(mockObject).methodToStub(captor.capture());
```

If you just want you mock to do nothing at all on a void method call, remeber that doing nothing is the **default** for void methods on mocks.

If for some reason you still need to call `doNothing`, you should take care with the parentheses position. It should look like this:

```
doNothing().when(mockObject).methodToStub(any());
```

or 
    doNothing().when(mockObject).methodToStub(captor.capture());

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually want nothing to happen when methodToStub is called. I understood (maybe incorrectly) that the ArgumentCaptor was needed because of the use of generics in the method being stubbed.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: you just want nothing to happen when the methodToStub is called? And mockObject is a a mock object created with mock(YourClass.class)?

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I must be going about this incorrectly. I want to stub out the call, but this class is getting injected elsewhere in the framework, so I'm not sure the mock will really work.

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to do a partial mock (mockObject works just like RealObject, EXCEPT when calling methodToStub, then it does nothing) then?  Would be useful if you could post a more complete example of what you are trying to do then; if youre framework is Spring I'm sure I can help, if not, a good, clear, concrete question will surely be answered by someone else.